# How to send id of a particular data from child to parent component in react through onClick event in the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This are my components in react and from child I am rendering a list of course dummy data. And on clicking on the div I want to send the id of that particular course to my parent component through onClick event. But I am not getting how to send the data from child and how to catch it in Parent.

CHILD:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classes from "./Modules.module.css";
import { COURSES_DATA } from "../../data/dummy_course_data";

const Modules = (props) => {
  const moduleDescriptionChangeHandler = () => {};

  return (
    <div className={classes.Modules}>
    <h1>Modules</h1>
    {COURSES_DATA.map((module) => (
    <div
      key={module.id}
      className={classes.ModuleItem}
      onClick={props.clicked.bind(module.id)}
    >
      <img src={module.icon} alt="icon" />
      <h2>{module.name}</h2>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
 );
};
export default Modules;
```

PARENT:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modules from "../components/Modules/Modules";
import ModuleDescription from "../components/Modules/ModuleDescription/ModuleDescription";
import classes from "./ModulesPage.module.css";

const ModulesPage = (props) => {
const [moduleId, setModuleId] = useState("");

const onClickDescriptionChangeHandler = (childmoduleId) => {
  setModuleId(childmoduleId);
 //console.log("childmoduleId", childmoduleId);
};

return (
  <div className={classes.ModulesPage}>
  <div className={classes.moduleItem}>
    <Modules clicked={onClickDescriptionChangeHandler} />
  </div>

  <div className={classes.moduleDescription}>
    <ModuleDescription />
  </div>
</div>
);
};

 export default ModulesPage;
```

Comment: it looks like you wrongly understand how the  bind method works. try props.clicked(module.id) there

Comment: @dm.shpak after adding what you said values are coming in the parent but I tried to put console.log in the parent what id is coming it is showing that all of the ids of the course data is coming inside the parent when the page is first loaded though I am not clicking any thing.

Comment: You can't bind a `this` value to an arrow function. If you want to use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#syntax) you need to pass your arguments starting at the second parameter. `this.clicked.bind(null, module.id)`. But you can also just `() => this.clicked(module.id)`

Comment: Also keep in mind that the implicitly passed `event` will still be passed, but will be the last parameter after all of your bound parameters.

Comment: @pilchard yeah you were right i didn't passed the null inside clicked function but instead of this.clicked(...) it will be props.clicked(...) as I am using functional component Thanks to you.